# A sheet of formulas for practical application of Integration?

Tags: reference-request, online-resources

does anyone know where I can find an organized formula sheet with formulas of the application of integration (triple and/or double integrals)?
Like finding the center of mass of a solid and such.

Although I could google the formulas when needed, It would be more convenient to have a formula sheet in my math binder (it will also help me memorise them!).

Thank you.

Edit: I'm a civil engineering student. So formulas for moments , center of mass, density and moments of inertia ( any other practical formulas?).

Comment: You'll need to be more specific, in the current scope of your question your whole binder will be filled, even if we stick to the basics.

Comment: What's "practical" depends entirely on what your application is. It's not reasonable to come up with a list of every interesting thing that can be defined via integration. You may have better luck asking a community more focused on civil engineering if you're looking for formulas particularly useful in that context.